# Wrapping figure only appears once

Tags: wrapfigure

I'm having problems using the `\wrapimage` environment.

When I insert an image, wrapped to the right, it appears just fine, but when I want to add a second image it doesn't appear.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}


\newcommand\tab[1][.5cm]{\hspace*{#1}}

\geometry{
    a4paper,
    total={170mm,257mm},
    left=20mm,
    top=20mm,
}

\begin{document}
    \title{Characterization of the amplifier using the protocol}
    \author{Group 11C - Handy Audio}
    \maketitle

    In order to verify the performance of our amplifier we applied the protocol described in \textit{Amplifier characteristics measurement protocol} obtaining the following results. 

    \section{Output power. $P_o$}
    \begin{table}[!h]
        \begin{tabular}{||m{0.3\textwidth} | m{0.7\textwidth} ||}
            \hline \hline
            Instruments and measure set up & 
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Power supply
                \item Waveform generator ($f=1\mathrm{kHz}, V_{pp}=0.8943\mathrm{V}$) 
                \item Oscilloscope              
            \end{itemize}
            \\
            \hline 
            Measured data &
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Output voltage: $V_o$
            \end{itemize}
            \\
            \hline
            Involved  variables, measured values and procedure & 
            Using \textit{Math Mode}, measure the voltage drop amplitude across the $8\mathrm\Omega$ resistor taking into account the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ factor of the RMS.\newline
            Applying the following formula:
            $$ P_o = I\cdot V_{o_{RMS}} =  \frac{V_{o_{RMS}}^{2}}{R_L} 
            = \frac{V_o^{2}}{2\cdot8\mathrm{\Omega}}$$
            we obtain the power delivered by the amplifier to the speaker.
            \\
            \hline \hline       
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.6\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth,keepaspectratio=true]{../Fotos/20161221/mesures_amplitud}
        \caption{Output signal at $f=1$kHz}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \noindent
    Specification: $1\mathrm{W} \le P_o \le 3\mathrm{W}$\\ \\
    Measurements:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item $V_o=\frac{V_{pp}}{2}=\frac{7.68\mathrm V}{2}=3.84$V
    \end{itemize}
    \noindent
    \\
    {\Large Result: $P_o=0.92$W  }
    \\ \\
    As we can see on Figure 1, the output signal amplitude does not reach the 4V required to achieve 1W of power, we could only reach 3.89V of amplitude at the output which gives us 0.92W of output power.
    \pagebreak

    \section{Energetic efficiency. $\eta$}
    \begin{table}[H]
        \begin{tabular}{||m{0.3\textwidth} | m{0.7\textwidth} ||}
            \hline \hline
            Instruments and measure set up & 
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Power supply
                \item Waveform generator ($f=1\mathrm{kHz}, V_{pp}=0.8943\mathrm{V}$)
                \item Oscilloscope 
            \end{itemize}
            \\
            \hline
            Measured data &
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Current consumption (power supply readout): $I_g$
                \item Power supply voltage: $V_{cc}$
            \end{itemize}
            \\
            \hline
            Involved  variables, measured values and procedure & 
            Using the readout provided by the power supply ($I_g$) and the previous measurement, using the following formula:
            $$ \eta = \frac{P_o}{I_g \cdot V_{cc}} $$
            we obtain the power efficiency of the amplifier.
            \\
            \hline \hline           
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.6\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth,keepaspectratio=true]{../Fotos/20161221/mesures_consum}
        \caption{Current consumption at $f=1$kHz}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \noindent
    Specification: $\eta \ge 80\%$ \\ \\
    Measurements:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item $I_g=0.21$A
        \item $V_{cc}=5.0$V
    \end{itemize}
    \noindent
    \\
    {\Large Result: $\eta=87.62\%$ }
    \\
    \pagebreak

    \section{Frequency response}
    \begin{table}[H]
        \begin{tabular}{||m{0.3\textwidth} | m{0.7\textwidth} ||}
            \hline\hline
            Instruments and measure set up & 
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Power supply
                \item Oscilloscope
                \item Waveform generator ($f\in(20, 20\mathrm k)\mathrm{Hz}, V_{pp}=0.8943\mathrm{V}$) 
            \end{itemize}
            \\
            \hline
            Measured data &
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Output voltage: $V_o$
            \end{itemize}
            \\
            \hline
            Involved  variables, measured values and procedure& 
            First we have to set up a fixed amplitude input signal and measure the output (voltage drop across the resistor: $V_R$). Using the cursors, we set up two thresholds: 
            \begin{itemize}
                \item $-1\mathrm{dB}$: $0.89 V_R$ 
                \item $-3\mathrm{dB}$: $0.70 V_R$
            \end{itemize} 
            Using the knob on the waveform generator we have to first sweep the frequency between 100Hz and 10kHz and check that the output signal does not go below the first threshold.\linebreak Then we have to repeat the frequency sweep but this time between 20Hz and 20kHz and check that the output signal does not go below the second threshold.\\
            \hline  \hline      
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \vspace{5mm}
    \noindent
    {\Large Result:\,} {\large OK}  if it satisfies both conditions
    \pagebreak

    \section{Total harmonic distortion + noise. $THD+N$}
    \begin{table}[H]
        \begin{tabular}{||m{0.3\textwidth} | m{0.7\textwidth} ||}
            \hline \hline
            Instruments and measure set up & 
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Power supply              
                \item Floating ground differential amplifier
                \item Waveform generator ($f=1\mathrm{kHz}, V_{pp}=0.8943\mathrm{V}$) 
                \item Spectrum analyzer (or an oscilloscope with FFT function)
            \end{itemize}
            \\
            \hline
            Measured data &
            \begin{itemize}
                \item FFT of the output signal
            \end{itemize}
            \\
            \hline
            Involved  variables, measured values and procedure& 
            Visualizing the spectrum of the output signal, we have to measure the amplitude of the harmonics and using the following formula\tablefootnote{$V_0$ is the amplitude of the fundamental harmonic\\\tab$V_n$ is the amplitude of the $n$th harmonic}:
            $$THD=\frac{\sqrt{V_1^2+V_2^2+\dots+V_N^2}}{V_0}$$
            we obtain the total harmonic distortion introduced by the amplifier.\\
            \hline \hline           
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
%   \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.6\textwidth}
%       \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth,keepaspectratio=true]{../Fotos/20161221/mesures_espectre}
%       \caption{Output signal spectrum at $f=1$kHz}
%   \end{wrapfigure}
    \noindent
    Specification: $THD \le 1\%$ \\ \\
    {\Large Result: $THD|_{N=5} =1.845\%$ }
\end{document}
```

And here is the output I get:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: welcome to TeX.SE.  Your MWE is not Minimal in the best sense.  I do have difficulties, in understanding your problem.  Where do you want to insert a "second" image?  How did you do that?  What happened exactly?

Comment: It seems that the `[H]` of second table causes the problem. If I replace it with `[!h]` it works fine.

Comment: hi @JPG , it's not working for me. If I replace H with !h the second image apears at the third page and it should appear at the second one.  Any ideas why?

Comment: Perhaps a problem of size? Difficult to help you without having the image files.

Comment: Here are the links of the images
[link](https://s29.postimg.org/4x5ce217r/mesures_amplitud.jpg)
[link](https://s29.postimg.org/fl93cwb6v/mesures_consum.jpg)

Comment: First, you aren't actually wrapping the text around the figure, so you could use minipages instead.  Second, since the figure extends past the end of the text, you probably need \WFclear to tell wrapfig to stop.

Comment: Also, you don't NEED to put tabulars inside table environments.